# cytoscape.js add node dynamicaly but mouseover doesn't work after

Tags: addition, nodes, cytoscape.js

The code adds a node dynamically but `mouseover` doesn't trigger for node "c"

```
// Mouseover function just give id node and position
cy.$('node').on('mouseover', function(evt) {
  var myClickedID = evt.cyTarget.id();
  console.log(myClickedID);
  console.log(cy.$('#' + myClickedID).position());
});

// add a node dynamicaly
cy.$('node').on('click', function(evt) {
  var elements = cy.add({
    group: 'nodes',
    data: { id: 'c' }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't bind to events on the added node.  It's the exact same behaviour in the DOM.  You can't expect that setting a listener on prior elements will automatically set listeners on newly added elements.

Use a delegate selector if you want to bind only once: http://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.on